# System of equations with 4 unknowns.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve this system of equations but I'm reaching a dead end.

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
xyz & = & x+y+z \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\
xyt & = & x+y+t \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)\\ 
xzt & = & x+z+t \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)\\ 
yzt & = & y+z+t \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)\\
\end{array}$$

So, (1)-(2) gives $$xyz-zyt=xy(z-t)=z-t\Rightarrow xy=1.$$

(3)-(4) gives $$xzt-yzt=zt(x-y)=x-y\Rightarrow zt=1.$$

This system reduces to $$\begin{array}{lcl}
xy & = & 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (5)\\
zt & = & 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (6)\\ 
\end{array}$$

One trivial solution is $x=y=z=t=\pm1,$ but this can't be because then I'd have divided by zero earlier in my simplifications.

How do I solve this one?

Comment: x=y=z=t=0 works heh

Comment: x=y=z=t=$\sqrt{3}$ works

Comment: Yes, got that from Wolfram Alpha too. I want to know how to algebraically prove those roots.

Comment: I have found a much much simpler way.

Comment: Can the solution be in $\mathbb{C}$? If yes, we also have $(i,i,-i,-i),$ $(-i,-i,i,i),$ $(i,-i,i,-i),$ $(-i,i,-i,i),$ $(i,-i,-i,i),$ $(-i,i,i,-i).$

Comment: How did you compute that?

Comment: @Parseval Use $xy=1$ instead of $z=t$. Plug this into the first two equations and you get $x+y = 0.$ $xy=1$ and $x+y=0$ gives $(x,y)\in\{(i,-i),(-i,i)\}.$ The third and fourth equation lead to $zt=1$ or $x=y$. We already know that $x\neq y$, thus we have $zt=1$ which in turn gives $(z,t)\in\{(i,-i),(-i,i)\}.$. Starting with different pairs of equations will give you all the possible combinations of $i$ and $-i$

Comment: @Parseval the missing *complex* solution using only equations (1), (2), and (3) comes from the last centered equation $(z^2-3)(z^2+1)=0$ which implies $z \in \{\pm \sqrt{3}, \pm i\}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subtracting $(1)$ and $(2)$, you establish

$$xy=1\lor z=t.$$

But plugging $xy=1$ in $(1)$ reduces it to

$$z=x+y+z$$ or $$x=-y,$$ which is not compatible.

Repeating with a circular permutation of the variables, the only possible solutions are trivially with $x=y=z=t$.

Comment: This was a nice one :) !

Comment: Or complex solutions ;-)

Comment: @M.Herzkamp: you should mention infinite solutions too.

Answer (score 5):

*We will find all solutions using only (1), (2), and (3).*

Making the difference between the first two equations you get $xy=1$ **or** $x=y$. Let us suppose that $xy=1$. Then $x,y$ have the same sign and are both $\neq 0$. This implies that
$$
z=xyz=x+y+z=x+\frac{1}{x}+z \implies x+\frac{1}{x}=0,
$$
which is impossibile since $|x+\frac{1}{x}|\ge 2$ for all non-zero reals $x$ (by AM-GM). Therefore $x=y$ ($\neq 1$ and $\neq -1$, otherwise $xy$ would still be $1$).

The first and second equations become (*)
$$
z(x^2-1)=2x \text{ and }t(x^2-1)=2x.
$$
In particular, $z=t$. This means the only two first equations imply $x=y \notin \{\pm 1\}$ and $z=t$.

Lastly, using (3), we get $xz^2=x+2z$, hecen we reduce to 
$$
x(z^2-1)=2z\text{ and }z(x^2-1)=2x.
$$
If $x=0$ then also $z=0$ and viceversa. Otherwise substituing the first into the second we get
$$
z=\frac{2x}{x^2-1}=\frac{4z}{\left(z^2-1\right) \left(\left(\frac{2z}{z^2-1}\right)^2-1\right)}=\frac{4z(z^2-1)}{4z^2-(z^2-1)^2}.
$$
Since $z\neq 0$ then 
$$
4z^2-(z^2-1)^2=4(z^2-1) \Leftrightarrow (z^2-3)(z^2+1)=0.
$$
Hence $|z|=\sqrt{3}$. Thus we have only the trivial solutions.

Comment: According to wolfram alpha, the solutions are $(0,\pm\sqrt{3}).$

Comment: Yes, I can't see anywhere that you wrote that 0 and $-\sqrt{3}$ are solutions.

Comment: I wrote $x=y$ and $z=t$. Also $x=0$ iff $z=0$, otherwise $|z|=\sqrt{3}$ from which $x=z$.

Comment: You made it ten times more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Except the fact that I never used the last equation.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti: right, not using the last equation makes it ten times more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Two trivial solutions.

Notice that by symmetry, if we let $x=y=z=t=a$, each equation is just $3a=a^3$, so we can have $(x,y,z,t)=(0,0,0,0), (\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3}), (-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: why is this down voted?

Comment: Define "by symmetry" 

I did not downvote.

Comment: Each equation is similar, in that it is of the form abc=a+b+c. it contains all 4 variations of this equation picking from the variables (x,y,z,t). and if all the variables are the same, each equation says the same thing

Comment: its like if a+b=ab, a+c=ac, b+c=bc

Comment: all 3 equations would be similar to abc

Comment: @SakethMalyala Wasn't *my* downvote, but `Two trivial solutions` doesn't count as an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry :( @dxiv

Answer (score 0):

No. $xyz-zyt=xy(z-t)=z-t\implies (\text{$xy=1$ or $z=t$})$.